# Maximum Level of a City

Tags: mob-wars

In the Header of each City, it says what the City is, what Level it is, and how to level it up. See picture below:

[image: City Header]

Then, when the requirements are done, you are presented with a link to level the city up, as seen below:

[image: City Header]

I want to know what the **maximum level of a city** is.

Answer (score 1):

The max city level seems to be 10. Although i couldn't find any list containing every city i found some listed below.

> The Godfather has just unlocked city levels in Moscow! Max out all Job
>   Tiers in Moscow in order to level up the city.  **Moscow can be leveled
>   up 10 times**, each level paying out Pawn Shop cards and new City
>   Achievements.  Those extra skill points are adding up!
>
> The Godfather has just unlocked city levels in Vegas! Max out all Job
>   Tiers in Vegas in order to level up the city.  **Vegas can be leveled up
>   10 times,** each level paying out Pawn Shop cards and new City
>   Achievements.
>
> ... **London can be leveled up 10 times,** ...

Its entirely possible for another city to be a higher/lower max level but i couldn't find information about that.

Source: http://mobwars.wordpress.com/